# lightning:combobox remove icons from listbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-combobox

If you notice the lightning:combobox component, you will see that inside the container of list options, there is an icon just in front of the options.

Is there any way to remove the icons?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is a single-select, readonly, drop down component, without the icons then perhaps the [lightning:select](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm) component would be something to consider?

Alternatively you can hide the icons using CSS: something along the lines of:

```
.THIS .slds-listbox__option.slds-is-selected .slds-listbox__icon-selected {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

(or even `display: none` if you'd also like to get rid of the space the icons occupy)